# SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 3

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have just installed `"body-parser": "^1.18.3"` (latest), and I added `express.use(bodyParser.json());`. Without using the `body parser` my routes work fine, but of course `req.body` is always `undefined`. I am not using `JSON.parse` anywhere inside my app, and I am certain that the error is coming from the package itself, unless I am missing a step while installing/using the package?

```
<pre>
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 3
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\Hafiz\Desktop\NowHiring\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\Hafiz\Desktop\NowHiring\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Hafiz\Desktop\NowHiring\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\Hafiz\Desktop\NowHiring\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Hafiz\Desktop\NowHiring\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
</pre>
```

P.S. The other similar questions are related to wrong use of `JSON.parse`, which is not the case here.

@deceze... seriously??? You think its off the topic.

`a problem that can no longer be reproduced` It is reproducible...

`a simple typographical error` No it is not just a matter of typo. FYI, `Body Parser` is a package that parse all your incoming request to the server. A normal person would expect the package to handle user input properly rather than throwing exception which could lead to a security issue. For the sake of an argument, let say it was just a typo. Sometimes it need an extra pair of eyes to identify a typo. I am sorry that my eyes are not as perfect as robotic eyes of yours! smh Nevertheless, it could help someone new that maybe confused between `JSON` and `Javascript Object Literals`.

Comment: Are you sure the incoming message is proper JSON ?

Comment: I just realized that I am missing quotes in my json. but that's dumb it throws an exception when it gets wrong formatted json. Wouldn't it crash the server if someone decided to attack?

Comment: @MarcQ. if you want you can add this as answer below and I will accept. It is indeed the answer I was looking for.

Comment: OK, will add answer in order to close the question. Cheers!

Comment: 1. JSON parser rejects invalid JSON as invalid, news at 11. There’s really no question to be answered here. 2. We don’t even *see* the JSON in question here, we can’t even tell you what error you made exactly.

Comment: 1. rejection and throwing exception are two different things. 2. If there is no answer here or we needed to see the JSON then how did Marc answered it by looking at the error WITHOUT seeing the JSON or the error I made. 3. You know what, I am not going to argue with you, because I know which pile you stand on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SyntaxError: Unexpected token X in JSON at position Y` part of the error message hints at an incorrect incoming JSON message.

Please note that the JSON specification is **stricter** than plain Javascript object literals, a really common mistake I make regularly myself :-).

Comment: Omg! I was in shock. Thanks ! I corrected my json and now it works.